# React Button Click Event Not Firing - One Button Works, One Button Doesnt

Tags: html, reactjs, button

I am hoping someone can help me.  I have two buttons in a react component. They both call the same javascript function.  One button works whereas the other button does not. Can anyone help me explain what is going on?

I have simplified the code to the smallest unit demonstrating the problem.

Here is the "react.buttonClickComponent.js" file:

```
class ButtonClick extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("componentDidMount");
    }

    buttonClickLaser = () => {
        console.log("buttonClickLaser()");
    }

    render() {
        console.log("inside render");

        return (
            <div>
                <button onclick={this.buttonClickLaser} >Button 1 - Doesnt Work</button>

                <button class="btn btn-default" onClick={this.buttonClickLaser}>Button 2 - This Button Works! <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span></button>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I am expecting both buttons to call the function buttonclickLaser() but Button 1 does not work!

Here is the HTML file that calls the react component:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/babel" src="react.buttonClickComponent.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            console.log("document loaded");
            ReactDOM.render(<ButtonClick />, document.getElementById('app'));
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Error is `onclick`, use `onClick`

```
 <button onClick={this.buttonClickLaser} >Button 1 - Doesnt Work</button>
```